# Getting run-time Error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)'

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting the above error when I run the line

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
```

I'm not sure why this could be happening but it's only happening on this particular workbook. Are there some sort of conflicts? What could be causing this? And how can I investigate?

Comment: I have experienced very weard crashes of that sort when working with large data stored in Excel. This is probably caused by an internal Excel issue and you cannot do shit about it. I would recommend anyone doing heavy duty processing using VBA to transition to Python or any other viable alternative.

Comment: Perhaps you named something else as `ThisWorkbook` ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to type:

```
Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
```